# using DATE in sql statement

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio, date, ms-access

I need some help!  I have been searching for the answer for this but nothing I come across and try seem to work! Keep in mind I am new to programming and I'm a first time poster on here!  I would appreciate any help and feedback!

I am creating a simple form that will track the current time a user clicks the start button and also a stop button. I am doing this in VB.NET and using Access as my database.  The user logs in with an id # and their password and then are prompted to press 1 of 2 buttons: either start or stop. When they click start, their id #, name, and the current time is added to a table in access.

The issue I am having is when they click the stop button. When stop is clicked, it needs to check the database and see if a start time has been logged for that user by their id # on the same day they are clicking end.

ex: user clicks start at 9am, clicks end at 10am = end time is logged in the database.
user clicks end without clicking start prior to clicking end = pop-up error message "start time was not entered"

This is currently what I have for this portion of my project:

```vb
Dim tdate As String

tdate = Date.Today

'connect to database
Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader("C:\DatabaseFile1.txt")
    Dim line As String

    line = sr.ReadLine()
    Reading_Line = CStr(line)
    Console.WriteLine(line)
 End Using


Database_Full_Path = Reading_Line

Cn = New ADODB.Connection

With Cn
    .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Database_Full_Path
    .Open()
End With



selstr2 = "SELECT Log.LastName, Log.FirstName, Log.IDnumber, Log.StartBreak, Log.EndBreak "
selstr2 = selstr2 & "FROM Log Log "
selstr2 = selstr2 & "WHERE ( Log.StartBreak = " & tdate & ") AND ( Log.IDnumber = " & id_F & ") "
```

It is adding all the information to my database, but is not properly checking if a start time has already been entered for the current date by user id #.

Comment: check something like `WHERE Log.StartBreak is not null AND  Log.IDnumber = id_F`

Comment: selstr2 = `"SELECT LastName, FirstName, IDnumber, StartBreak, EndBreak FROM Log WHERE StartBreak is not null AND IDnumber = "+ id_F`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. When I added that to the select string, I got an error saying variable has been used before it is assigned a value. I tried it on the other two strings and it duplicates it and I get An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' due to a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

try this (adding single quote around the date):

```
selstr2 = "SELECT Log.LastName, Log.FirstName, Log.IDnumber, Log.StartBreak, Log.EndBreak "
selstr2 = selstr2 & "FROM Log Log "
selstr2 = selstr2 & "WHERE ( Log.StartBreak = '" & tdate & "') AND ( Log.IDnumber = " & id_F & ") "
```

Comment: That looked like it was going to work, but I still got an error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred.
Additional information: Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Comment: is Log.StartBreak a date field?  is Log.IDnumber a numeric field?

Comment: tdate may not be formatted correctly for SQL ... what's it look like?

Comment: i defined tdate as an expression. `Dim tdate As String

tdate = Date.Today
`

Comment: hmmm ... what about id_F ... is it the same format as Log.IDnumber ?

Comment: yes, that is correct. id_F is the expression i used for the id number that is entered into the textbox. id_F = IDnumber